# Modifying the Employee Information field in Suite Admin SDK Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-admin-sdk

Is there a way to modify these fields through the Admin SDK without manually doing it through the admin console? Specifically under the employee information, the job title, type of employee, manager's email and department.

[image]

I've looked at https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users and https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/admin_directory_v1.users.html#insert but I don't see any parameter that you can specify these fields in.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields are kind of scattered around but we can figure it out by filling them manually on a test user and running a [`users.get`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get) on them.

So for an employee that looks like this:

[image: Employee fields]

The API result is the following (after removing the irrelevant fields):

```
{
  "externalIds": [
    {
      "value": "ID-123",
      "type": "organization"
    }
  ],
  "relations": [
    {
      "value": "example@domain.com",
      "type": "manager"
    }
  ],
  "organizations": [
    {
      "title": "My Job Title",
      "primary": true,
      "customType": "",
      "department": "My Department",
      "description": "My Employee Type",
      "costCenter": "My Cost Center"
    }
  ],
  "locations": [
    {
      "buildingId": "My Building ID",
      "floorName": "My Floor Name",
      "floorSection": "My Floor Section"
    }
  ]
}
```

So from this we can deduce that *Job Title* corresponds to `organizations.title`, *Type of employee* corresponds to `organizations.description`, *Manager's email* corresponds to `relations.value` that also has a `relations.type = manager` and *Department* corresponds to `organizations.department`.

Do note that as explained in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users) that you were looking at, these fields can hold multiple values, so the user can have multiple `organizations`, but the one that shows in the Admin console is the one marked as `primary`, they can have multiple relations other than manager such as `assistant`, `spouse`, etc. They can have multiple locations and so on.

Generally what will be displayed in the Admin console are the primary fields. Any secondary values may not show up but you can still retrieve them via the API. Most likely they're meant for custom applications that can take advantage of reading these multiple fields, while the console only shows the most relevant fields (as decided by Google).